# Android - Simple Custom View question

Tags: java, android, graphics, view

I have a custom View in which i drawBitmap and then I scale the View to 1.5 scale factor.

After the scaling (zoom gesture) - I get the width and height of the view and it's the same just like the initial size. Thus, I have:

```
canvas.scale(1.5, 1.5, 0, 0);
measure(getWidth()*1.5, getHeight()*1.5);
```

and it calls onMeasure with the correct dimensions:

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(heightMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    }
}
```

But after onMeasure is finished, if I get the width and height of the View, it's again the same as before...

And I need it to be the scaled size ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you need to use a Matrix here, apply it to your image/canvas, and then use [postscale()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#postScale%28float,%20float%29) method to make it effective.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

To resize the View you need to have its parent lay out again. Make two calls on your View: First specify the new size view `View.setLayoutParams(LayoutParams)`, then call `View.requestLayout()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method getMeasuredWidth/Height(), that should give you what the View's measured values are at drawing time.